# Biblatex: backref at the very end and year after title when referencing a reprint

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` to reference a reprint. I need to change the following in my MWE: i) the backref showing the page number should be at the very end (after the period) ii) the year of the reprinted book (test2) should go after the title and between parenthesis. So I would like to achieve the following:

```
Foo, John (2012), Test 1. Helsinki:Blah Press. Rpt. as Test 2 (2013). Chicago: Baz Press. (cit. on p. 1)
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{foo12,
  author      = {John Foo},
  title       = {Test 1},
  year        = {2012},
  publisher   = {Blah Press},
  address     = {Helsinki},
  related     = {foo13},
  relatedtype = {reprintas}
 }
@Book{foo13,
  author    = {John Foo},
  title     = {Test 2},
  year      = {2013},
  publisher = {Baz Press},
  address   = {Chicago},
 }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{foo12}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution were first we create a copy of `pageref` bib macro and we call it `mypageref` (copied from `biblatex.def`)

```
\newbibmacro*{mypageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}
```

then we empty the definition of `pageref`

```
\renewbibmacro{pageref}{}
```

and finally, we instruct to use the new  definition at  the end of a reference using the `finentry` hook.

```
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock\usebibmacro{mypageref}\finentry}
```

To change the  appearance of the reprint one has to provides a definition of `related:reprints` macro. Here is a simplified version of it (it does not check if the authors are the same, it does not include information about eventual editors, ...)

```
\newbibmacro{related:reprintas}[1]{
  \entrydata{#1}{
    \printfield{title}
    \mkbibparens{\printdate}
    \setunit{\adddot\addspace}
    \clearfield{date}
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}
  }
}
```

[image]

PS Moving the back ref after the reprint makes ambiguous  whether the original work or the reprint is cited at the pages given the backref.

Comment: Thank you! Can you place the year of the reprinted book between parenthesis and after the title. Like this: "Test 2 (2013)"?

Comment: Thanks again! I changed the question following your suggestion.